# css align image in line with 2 text lines

Tags: css

[image]

`mytext2` should be right down `mytext` without any blank spaces. The picture, and the 2 text lines lay on a panel.

I tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` property but still wont work. I try also to add a table with 1 row and 2 columns, but is there any chance to make this easily?

Thanks in advance

Here is what I want:

[image]

Comment: Try a `float:left` clause on the picture and `width:100%; text-align:right;` on a div containing your text segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `mytext1` & `mytext2` in one ***wrapeer div*** & `float` it to right